# How to get back the new value after an update in a embedded array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following MongoDB collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("56d6a7292c06e85687f44541"),
    "name": "My ranking list",
    "rankings": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55542"),
            "name": "Ranking 1",
            "score": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543"),
            "name": "Ranking 2",
            "score": 10
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55544"),
            "name": "Ranking 3",
            "score": 15
        },
    ]
}
```

Here is how I increase the score of a given ranking:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("56d6a7292c06e85687f44541"), "rankings._id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543") },
    { $inc : { "rankings.$.score" : 1 } }
);
```

How do I get the new score value? In the previous query I increase the second ranking from 10 to 11... How do I get this new value back after the update?

Comment: You could use [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are on MongoDB 3.0 or newer, you need to use the [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db-collection-findoneandupdate)  and use `projection` option to specify the subset of fields to return. You also need to set `returnNewDocument` to `true`.  Of course you need to use the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator here because you cannot use a positional projection and return the new document.

As someone pointed out:

> You should be using [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db-collection-findoneandupdate) because [`.findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) is highlighed as deprecated in every official language driver. The other thing is that the syntax and options are pretty consistent across drivers for `.findOneAndUpdate()`. With `.findAndModify()`, most drivers don't use the same single object with "query/update/fields" keys. So it's a bit less confusing when someone applies to another language to be consistent. Standardized API changes for `.findOneAndUpdate()` actually correspond to server release 3.x rather than 3.2.x. The full distinction being that the shell methods actually lagged behind the other drivers ( for once ! ) in implementing the method. So most drivers actually had a major release bump corresponding with the 3.x release with such changes.

```js
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate( 
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("56d6a7292c06e85687f44541"), 
         "rankings._id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543") 
    },  
    { $inc : { "rankings.$.score" : 1 } },  
    { 
        "projection": { 
            "rankings": { 
                "$elemMatch": { "_id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543") } 
            }
        }, 
        "returnNewDocument": true 
    }
)
```

From MongoDB 3.0 onwards, you  need to use [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) and the `fields` options also you need to set `new` to `true` in other to return the new value.

```js
db.collection.findAndModify({   
    query: { 
        "_id": ObjectId("56d6a7292c06e85687f44541"), 
        "rankings._id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543") 
    },     
    update: { $inc : { "rankings.$.score" : 1 } },       
    new: true,  
    fields: { 
        "rankings": { 
            "$elemMatch": { "_id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543") }
        }  
    }
})
```

Both queries yield:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d6a7292c06e85687f44541"),
        "rankings" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543"),
                        "name" : "Ranking 2",
                        "score" : 11
                }
        ]
}
```