# Does MongoDB's $elemMatch projection guarantee the returned element is the same one that was matched in the query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a collection with this single document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("…"),
    "cartId" : "61",
    "items" : [
        {
            "prodType" : "hardware",
            "prod" : "screwdriver",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "prodType" : "hardware",
            "prod" : "hammer",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "prodType" : "decor",
            "prod" : "vase",
            "checked": false
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to do `findAndModify` to find *any* hardware product and modify its `checked` field. Then it will look like this:

```
db.col.findAndModify({
    query: {
        items: {
            $elemMatch: {
                prodType: "hardware"
            }
        }
    },
    update: {
        $set: {
            "items.$.checked": true
        }
    }
})
```

Okay, but this isn't the whole story. `findAndModify` will return the *whole* matched document, and I want to project specifically the array item that was matched (and also modified), so I'll add a `fields` section to my query:

```
db.col.findAndModify({
    query: {
        items: {
            $elemMatch: {
                prodType: "hardware"
            }
        }
    },
    update: {
        $set: {
            "items.$.checked": true
        }
    },
    fields: {
        items: {
            $elemMatch: {
                prodType: "hardware"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

And now to the question: does MongoDB guarantee that the returned array item from my query is the exact same one that was matched (and modified) in the `update` section even though we have two items matching the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

YES. It will return only the first sub-document that matched your criteria and  was modified in the update section as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946989/how-to-get-back-the-new-value-after-an-update-in-a-embedded-array)

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs, then yes - the projected array element is the exact one that was modified using the same one modified by the positional operator.

[$ (update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#definition) states:

> the positional `$ operator` acts as a placeholder for the **first** element that matches the `query document`

and [$elemMatch (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#definition) states:

> The `$elemMatch` operator limits the contents of an `<array>` field from the query results to contain only the **first** element matching the `$elemMatch` condition

They both apply to the *first* array element so it directly implies that the modified array element is the one that is projected