# Get ID of object after $push with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently updating an embedded document using the following:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(user,{$push:{"position":
    {title:req.body.title,location:req.body.location,start:req.body.start,term:req.body.term,description:req.body.description}}}).exec(function (err, result) 
{
  if (result){

    console.log(result.position);
   }
   else{


   }
```

The object is successfully inserting into the "positions" section of the user collection, however, I need the _id of the object when its pushed.
When I log the result array I get all of the positions in the array except for the one I just entered, however it is in the database.
Is there any way of getting the _id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get back the new value after an update in a embedded array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946989/how-to-get-back-the-new-value-after-an-update-in-a-embedded-array)