# $ projection in mongoDB findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to build a simple task queue with express and mongoose. The idea is acquire a single client and return campaign id and client id (which is a subdocument of campaign). Each time someone acquires a client, its status code is set to 1. I've come up with the following query:

```
router.post('/lease', (err, res) => {
    Campaign.findOneAndUpdate({'isEnabled': true,  'clients.contact_status_code': 0}, {
            '$set': { 'clients.$.contact_status_code': 1 },
        },
        {
            new: true,
            projection: {
                'clients.$': true,
            },
        },
        (err, campaign) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }

            res.json(campaign);
        }
    );
});
```

But all i'm getting after connecting to this endpoint is this:

```
{"_id":"591483241a84946a79626aef","clients":[{},{}]}
```

It seems to me that the problem is with the $ projection, but I have no idea how to fix this.

EDIT: I tried using the following code, utilizing $elemMatch:

```
router.post('/lease', (err, res) => {
    Campaign.findOneAndUpdate({'isEnabled': true,  'clients.contact_status_code': 0}, {
            '$set': { 'clients.$.contact_status_code': 1 },
        },
        {
            new: true,
            projection: {
                clients: {
                    '$elemMatch': {contact_status_code: 1},
                }
            },
        },
        (err, campaign) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }

            res.json(campaign);
        }
    );
});
```

Unfortunately, each request yields the first subdocument in the collection, that matched the criteria -- not specifically the one that was updated. Here is an example:

Say, i have the following document in mongo:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("591493d95d48e2738b0d4317"),
    "name" : "asd",
    "template" : "{{displayname}}",
    "isEnabled" : true,
    "clients" : [
            {
                    "displayname" : "test",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("591493d95d48e2738b0d4319"),
                    "contact_status_code" : 0
            },
            {
                    "displayname" : "client",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("591493d95d48e2738b0d4318"),
                    "contact_status_code" : 0
            }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
```

}

I run the query for the first time and get the following result:

```
{"_id":"591493d95d48e2738b0d4317","clients":[{"displayname":"test","_id":"591493d95d48e2738b0d4319","contact_status_code":1}]}
```

Notice client id "591493d95d48e2738b0d4319" -- this time it runs as expected. But when i run the same query the second time, I get absolutely the same object, although I expect to get one with id "591493d95d48e2738b0d4318".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get back the new value after an update in a embedded array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946989/how-to-get-back-the-new-value-after-an-update-in-a-embedded-array)

Comment: @Veeram the answer suggests to use $elemMatch to query by _id. Unfortunately, I don't know the _id beforehand :\

Comment: That is the answer for that post. You can update to use your own criteria for elemmatch. Something like `{ 
        "projection": { 
            "clients": { 
                "$elemMatch": { "contact_status_code" : 1} 
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @Veeram There is no specific criteria that I can directly map to changed element. And if I try '$elemMatch': {contact_status_code: 1}, it simply always returns the first client in array -- not specifically the one that was updated in query.

Comment: Do you just need the whole `clients` array ? Why is `contact_status_code` not a specific criteria  after all that is what you've used for finding this element in the first place ? May be its `{ "projection": { "clients": { "$elemMatch": { "contact_status_code" : 0} } } }`, but this should bring back the changed sub element.

Comment: @Veeram no, I don't need the whole array -- just the single subdocument from it, the one that was updated by `clients.$.contact_status_code`. I've tried using the code you suggested (see edited answer), but it always yields the very first element of the array (so, always the same result, on each request) up until I just run out of available clients with contact_status_code = 0. Then it just switches to next campaign, again, yielding only the first element of array with each request.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Yeah looks like it is not possible. More here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6865

Comment: @Veeram I've managed to find (a bit hacky) way to get the _id from this query. You can check out my proposed answer if you like :)
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue was with `new: true`

Here is a working example:

```
Campaign.findOneAndUpdate({'isEnabled': true,  'clients.contact_status_code': 0}, {
            '$set': { 'clients.$.contact_status_code': 1 },
        },
        {
            //new: true <-- this was causing the trouble
            projection: {
                clients: {
                    '$elemMatch': {contact_status_code: 0}, // 0 because the old record gets matched
                },
            },
        },
        (err, campaign) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }

            res.json(campaign);
        }
    );
```

I assume, when the `new:true` is set, mongo loses the matching context. This approach returns the old record, unfortunately, but that still serves my needs to get the _id.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope this works the way you describe. I can't find any documentation for this behavior. Make sure to add all the necessary test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are getting the campaign id, but you also want clients.$, have you tried clients.$._id?

Comment: Yes, campaign id is ok -- the problem is specifically with fetching the right subdocument. Unfortunately, clients.$._id yields the same result: array of empty objects.

Answer (score 0):

## Update for node MongoDB 3.6 driver

- unlike `findAndModify` the function `findOneAndUpdate`  doesn't have the option new in its options  [list](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)
- **But** you can use instead *returnDocument*
- returnDocument    accept `before` OR `after`

  - When set to `after`,returns the updated document rather than the original
  - When set to `before`,returns the original document rather than the updated.

> The default is `before`.

> *returnOriginal* is ***Deprecated*** Use returnDocument instead

- Here is a working example:

```js
const filter={'isEnabled': true,  'clients.contact_status_code': 0}
    const update={'$set': { 'clients.$.contact_status_code': 1 }}
    const options={
                returnDocument: 'after' //returns the updated document
                projection: {
                    clients: {
                        '$elemMatch': {contact_status_code: 0}, 
                        // 0 because the old record gets matched
                    },
                },
            }
    Campaign.findOneAndUpdate(filter,update, options
            ,(err, campaign) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.send(err);
                }
                res.json(campaign);
            }
        );
```

[findOneAndUpdate Node.js MongoDB Driver API 3.6 documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)