# Mongoose: MongoError: >1 field while trying to project out $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to project out only the matched element of an array, in the updated version. But I'm getting the error: **"MongoError: >1 field in obj: { _id: 0, lotes.$: 1 }"**

If I remove 'new: true', it works. But then I have the doc before the update. And I would really like the updated version.

What's wrong? How can I fix it?

The Offer doc is something like:

```
 {
      _id
      series: [ Serie ]
    }
```

Serie structure is something like:

```
{
  _id
  public.available: Number
  public.expDate: Date
}
```

I'm using Mongoose:

```
        var query = {
            '_id': offerId, 
            'series': { 
                $elemMatch: {
                    '_id': serieId,
                    'public.available': {$gt:0},
                    'public.expDate': {$gt: now}
                }
            }
        };
        var update = { 
            $inc: { 'series.$.public.available' : -1 }
        };
        var options = { // project out just the element found, updated
            new:true,
            select: {
              '_id': 0,
              'series.$': 1 
            }
        };

        Offers.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
        .then( element => {
             ...
        }
```

Comment: Try with `$elemMatch` projection instead... `select: {
              '_id': 0,
              'series': { 
                $elemMatch: {
                    'public.available': { $gt :0 },
                    'public.expDate': { $gt: now } 
                }
            }
            }`

Comment: I just tried Anthony. I got the error "MongoError: >1 field in obj: { _id: 0, series: { $elemMatch: { public.available: { $gt: 0 }, public.expDate: { $gt: new Date(1534944191392) } } } }"

Comment: I can't find explanation for this error anywhere..

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920243/projection-in-mongodb-findoneandupdate

Comment: This will definetly work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946989/how-to-get-back-the-new-value-after-an-update-in-a-embedded-array

Comment: Hmm, so it seems to be a problem with Mongoose actually, because the second solution, using mongodb drivers, is supposed to work. But with Mongoose (first link) there's no way to retrieve the updated document.... The only update I'll have is the "-1" in the available field. If don't use 'new:true' and get back the original document, can a safely infer "available -1" to send back to the front-end?

Comment: what is your mongoose and mongodb version?

Comment: Mongoose 5.2.0 and MongoDB 4.0.0

Comment: I'm using MongoDB with replica set, using npm run-rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Anthony Winzlet pointed out in the links, there seems to be an issue with Mongoose, in which if you use 'new:true', you can't project out the $elemMatch.

So my solution was to keep using 'new:true' only, without projections. And reduce the array later on to get the $elemMatch:

```
.then( (result) => {
  var aux = result.series.reduce((acu, serie, index) => {
    if (serie._id == req.params.serieId) return index;
  });
  var element = result.series[aux];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else experiencing this error, it is also the most common error when trying to perform an illegal action such as trying to update a database element inside of a findOne request.

Making sure your request is correct, such as findOneAndUpdate should be your first port of call when you get this error.